# How to apply different validation to different ng-repeat field and calculate its total automatically in ng repeat itself

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

Example Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Class</td>
        <td> Input one </td>
        <td> Input two </td>
        <td> Total </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat= "x in records">
        <td>My {{x.class}} </td>
        <td><input type="tel" ng-value="x.tel" ng-model="telephone"></td>
        <td><input type="tel" ng-value="x.inone" ng-model="inone"></td>
        <td><input type="tel" ng-value="x.intwo" ng-model="intwo"></td>
        <td><input type="tel" ng-value="x.total" ng-model="total"></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="text-center"> <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="mydata(records)"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Initially  ng repeat records contains only details part bydefault.

```
$scope.records = [
       {
            "class" : "Personal",

        },
        {
            "class" : "Socail",

        },
    ]
```

After submit, angular dynamically add those field which filled by user

Intially User will see only

1.Class part with 3 blank input field for inone, intwo and total and one blank telephone field.

What I want

1.There should be validation to telephone field of

```
A. Personal class which allow only 6 digits, and 

B. for Social class it should allow 10 digits.
```

2. The range for entering value in Personal's inone field is 0-10 and intwo field is 11-30.
3. The range for entering value in Social's inone field is 30-40 and intwo field is 40-60.

   4.Total field should calculate total of whatever entered in inone and intwo model of there respective class .Note that total field is generated from ng repeat so we cannot directly make total.

Comment: unfortunately, this question is rather confusing.  if you only ever have two rows, and each row has different requirements, then using `ng-repeat` doesn't make any sense.  that being said, the requirements themselves don't make sense.  it's not clear what you mean when you say the "range" for entering values;  are you saying in the first field you want 6 numbers but want all 6 of them to be 0-5? and how can you have a 10 *digit* field, with a range from 11-15?

Answer (score 0):

What about something along the line ...

```
<td ng-if="x.class=='Personnal'"><input type="tel" ng-maxlength="5"  ng-model="x.inone" ng-change="x.total=x.inone+x.intwo"></td>
<td ng-if="x.class=='Social'"><input type="tel" ng-maxlength="5" ng-model="x.inone"></td>
<td ng-if="x.class=='Personnal'"><input type="tel" ng-minlength="11" ng-maxlength="15" ng-model="x.intwo" ng-change="x.total=x.inone+x.intwo"></td>
<td ng-if="x.class=='Social'"><input type="tel" ng-minlength="16" ng-maxlength="20"  ng-model="intwo"></td>
```

Tu sum it up :

- ng-value is useless, bind your data directly to x.[value]
- use ng-if to switch between the different classes
- use ng-minlength/ng-maxlength for the validation
- use ng-change to recompute total everytime, you may want to add a readonly/disabled flag in the total field. If total is not a string concatenation, use a function that will be called in your controller for the proper conversion and sum it up.

Comment: x.inone+x.intwo can not be done directly. You must have to parse.

Comment: @AnkitVadi  *If total is not a string concatenation, use a function that will be called in your controller for the proper conversion and sum it up.*